# How to add a 2d tensor to every 2d tensor from a 3d tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to add a 2d tensor to every 2d tensor from a 3d tensor.
Let's say i have a  tensor `a` with `(2,3,2)` shape and a tensor `b` with `(2,2)` shape.

```
a = [[[1,2],
      [1,2],
      [1,2]],
     [[3,4],
      [3,4],
      [3,4]]]

b = [[1,2], [3,4]]

#the result i want to get
a[:, 0, :] + b
a[:, 1, :] + b
a[:, 2, :] + b
```

I wanna know if there is a method in pytorch that can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way of doing this would be to add an extra second dimension to `b` and use broadcasting to add:

```
a = torch.Tensor([[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]],[[3,4],[3,4],[3,4]]])
b = torch.Tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
a += b.unsqueeze(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do:

```
a = [[[1,2],
      [1,2],
      [1,2]],
     [[3,4],
      [3,4],
      [3,4]]]

b = [[1,2], [3,4]]

a = torch.LongTensor(a)
b = torch.LongTensor(b)

a[:, 0, :] += b
a[:, 1, :] += b
a[:, 2, :] += b

print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[[2, 4],
         [2, 4],
         [2, 4]],

        [[6, 8],
         [6, 8],
         [6, 8]]])
```

You can do the same thing as follows.

```
a = (a.transpose(0, 1) + b).transpose(0, 1)
print(a) # prints the same tensor
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution @SinaAfrooze proposed is correct but it's not the fastest.

TL;DR: `torch.add(b.unsqueeze(1), a)` is faster.

---

Benchmarks:

```
import torch
a = torch.Tensor([[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]],[[3,4],[3,4],[3,4]]])
b = torch.Tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
z = a + b.unsqueeze(1)

%timeit k = torch.add(b.unsqueeze(1), a)
4.08 µs ± 25.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit z = a + b.unsqueeze(1)
4.14 µs ± 29 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

torch.equal(k, z)
True
```